# How to add an additional class to a table from context in Django

Tags: django

I have 2 functions one for MarketingMessage and another for Slider.

I have already a function for MarketingMessage and I want to add the Slider because the below function is not working correctly I want to combine them together as they are from the same model

This is the original function that I want to add to it

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message'] = None
        return context
```

this is the function that I want to get rid of and include it to the above one

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['sliders'] = Sliders.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except Sliders.DoesNotExist:
            context['sliders'] = None
        return context
```

This is the model

```
class MarketingMessage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    message = models.TextField(
        max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Slider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='Marketing')
    header_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    footer_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    button_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've tried combining them into this function but it is not working

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message':MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp'),
                    'slider':Slider.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp')
                    ]
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message': None,
                    'Slider':None]
        return context
```

Thank you all

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Can you not just take the logic from your second `get_context_data` and add it to your first one? Are you trying to combine `MarketingMessage` and `Slider` so that they are a single model instead of one?

Comment: @DragonBobZ yes they are in one model already I want to combine them in one function

Comment: One of us misunderstands something. In the code you've shown, `MarketingMessage` and `Slider` are two separate classes that inherit `models.Model`, making them two different models. Now it may be the case that you have a single view class (inheriting from `views.View`). I suppose that's probably what you mean. So my answer is to manually take the logic for adding `sliders` to your context from your second function and simply add it to the first. No fuss, no muss, no magic.

Comment: @DragonBobZ this is what I did but nothing is happening `    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message':MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp'),
                    'slider':Slider.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp')
                    ]
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message': None,
                    'Slider':None]
        return context`

Comment: Do you mind adding what you've tried already to your question? This is very difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @DragonBobZ  I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your new function. It has several syntax errors. I will write a corrected version that behaves exactly as you've indicated and then make some suggestions.

Your new view looks like this:

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
            context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message'] = None
            context['slider'] = None
        return context
```

This issue is that in the above, `Slider.DoesNotExist` is not handled. The way I see it, you have two good options.

1. Set them both to `None` if either query fails

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
            context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        # this will be triggered when either exception is thrown.
        except (MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist, Slider.DoesNotExist):
            context['marketing_message'] = None
            context['slider'] = None
        return context
```

2. Individually determine if they should be `None` when queries fail

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message'] = None
        try:
            context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except Slider.DoesNotExist:
            context['slider'] = None
        return context
```

It really depends on what you want to do with the context when one of them fails.